# How to download AWS logs/stats

Tags: amazon-ec2, logging, amazon-web-services

The graphs are nice but how can I download stats to analyze AWS performance?

Is there an API call that I can make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I believe you're talking about CloudWatch and so, taking a look at the CloudWatch API, there's the `GetMetricStatistics` API call:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html

Some examples on how to use it with, say PHP, are available as well:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonCloudWatch/get_metric_statistics

You'll most likely want to take a look at `ListMetrics` first so you can see all the bits available to you.